# Absolute positioning causing horizontal scroll bars with image

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position, absolute

I have a situation where I have an image where I need it to be able to be "out of it's bounds"; works fine on larger screens, but causes horizontal scroll bars on smaller screens.

I have the image set to `position: absolute`, so thought this wouldn't cause this issue?

I have tried using `overflow: hidden;` on it's parent as well as other ancestors, but all this does is hide the overflow completely; I don't want to hide the overflow *visually*, I just want to get rid of the scroll bars.

**CodePen Example:** https://codepen.io/gutterboy/pen/RxeMGx

**HTML:**

```
<div id="home" class="site-container">
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="details col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                    <section id="about" class="intro">
                        <p>s esse dicamus. Hoc dixerit potius Ennius: Nimium boni est, cui nihil est mali. Quid ergo hoc loco intellegit honestum?</p>
                        <p>Vide, quantum, inquam, fallare, Torquate. Sed fortuna fortis; Prodest, inquit, mihi eo esse animo. Ut id aliis narrare gestiant? Quare conare, quaeso. Ipse Epicurus fortasse redderet, ut Sextus Peducaeus, Sex.</p>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="photo col-md-7 col-lg-7">
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9b/eb/39/9beb39ffdbc43f20bd886b88b45edd59.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Paint" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:** *(Note, uses Bootstrap 3.6 as well)*

```
#home {

  &.site-container {
    margin: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
  }

    .hero {

      .details {
        padding: 15px;
      }

        .photo {
          position: relative;

            @media (min-width: 992px) {
                min-height: 458px;
            }

            @media (min-width: 1199px) {
                min-height: 553px;
            }          

            img {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;              
                transform: translate(15%);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you're not setting it as a background?

like so ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpmJxz

```
&.site-container {
 margin: 20px;
 border: 2px solid #000;
 background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9b/eb/39/9beb39ffdbc43f20bd886b88b45edd59.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right 10% bottom;
 background-size: 30%;
 padding: 10% 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, it wasn't set as a background initially as it needed to be responsive with the use of bootstraps `.img-responsive` class; secondly, making backgrounds go outside their bounds is even more difficult; though I think I may have done it once before using negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the page to not have a horizontal scroll use this

```
html{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I don't particularly like applying that to the whole page as it can then allow you to miss other issues your page has.

Comment: your problem is probably in this part of the code `img {
                      
                transform: translate(15%);
            }` this part forces the image to go out of the html boundaries when the margins and padding of your main content are less than a 15% of your page

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure why it doesn't work on CodePen, but I tried it locally and applying `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `.hero` class appears to work.

I'm still curious why it wouldn't work on any closer ancestors, so if you can post a better answer on *why* or a solution for it to work on a closer ancestor then more than happy to select your answer instead.